# Sd card and its directory

Tags: sd-card, mount

My phone (a refurbished Kyocera Hydro Icon running non-rooted Android 4.3) shows storage info of a sd card in picture 1. What's the path of its mounting point?

The size matching in picture 1 and 2 suggests its directory is `/storage/sdcard0`.

But ES File Explorer shows the content of /storage/sdcard0 isn't empty after I unmount the sd card. Picture 3 and 4 are before and after I unmount the sd card.

I can't find the sd card in the back of the phone. See picture 5. Where is it? (Update: I found the 2GB sd card, it is a little black thing, a little vague to see in the picture 5)

Thanks.

[image: Storage in Settings] [image: Storage in ES file manager]
<sup>Storage as shown in *Settings* (left) and *ES file manager*</sup>

[image: both cards mounted] [image: external card removed]
<sup>`sdcard0` with both cards mounted (left, note the `internalSD` folder) and with the external card removed</sup>

[image: SD card is inserted]
<sup>There's an SD card inserted. Click the image for a larger variant if you don't believe</sup>

I've checked with `mount` and `df` while both cards are mounted, and with the external card umounted:

[image: mount] [image: mount]
<sup>output of `mount` with the external mounted (left) and unmounted (click images for larger variants)</sup>

[image: df]  [image: df]

<sup>output of `df` with the external mounted (left) and unmounted (click images for larger variants)</sup>

Comment: *SD card* on newer Android phones, when referring to `/storage/sdcard0`, is meant in the sense of *internal storage* usable *as* an SD card. You should not attempt to unmount it, because it automatically gets remounted, because it's needed by many apps as their secondary storage to store large amounts of data (`/data/data/` is the primary but smaller one).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checking your pics again: that device seems to have a weird mounting set up, which I've never seen before on an Android device. `/storage/sdcard0` indeed is your internal SD. But as soon as the external card is mounted, some kind of "[overlay file system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_mount)" seems to be initialized, blending it in with the internal card as if it were a single device. You can see that by the fact that, when unmounting, some entries from pic#3 disappear (pic#4; of course the files from the external card) while some remain (those on the internal card).

To find out where the external card is mounted physically, you can use the `mount` or `df` command at a terminal prompt: no root required for that, a simple terminal app will do or, alternatively, access via `adb shell` (see: [adb](/questions/tagged/adb) and [its tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/adb/info)).

---

**Edit:** After having collected `df` output with and without the external card mounted, the situation looks a bit more confusing. Here's what's happening in your case:

- the internal SD card gets mounted to `/storage/sdcard0`, as it should be.
- when the external card is inserted,

  1. the internal one gets unmounted
  2. the external card gets mounted to `/storage/sdcard0`
  3. the internal card gets mounted to `/storage/sdcard0/internalSD`
- when the external card is unmounted, things reverse again

So `/storage/sdcard0` never shows "empty", but the content "changes". Relevant parts of `df` output to confirm this:

```
# df run with the external card mounted:
/storage/sdcard0              1.9G …
/storage/sdcard0/internalSD   1023.7M …
# df run after unmounting the external card:
/storage/sdcard0              1023.7M …
```

Check with the sizes to confirm. Another proof is the `mount` output:

```
# mount with both cards mounted:
/dev/block/vold/179:65 /storage/sdcard0 vfat
/dev/block/vold/179:30 /storage/sdcard0/internalSD vfat
# after unmounting the external card:
/dev/block/vold/179:30 /storage/sdcard0 vfat
```

Here you clearly see the device (first column) mounted to `/storage/sdcard0` changes (which explains why I wanted the `mount` output in the first place). So no UnionFS: the output also clearly shows both cards using [VFAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Allocation_Table#VFAT). Changing contents in the `/storage/sdcard0` directory are easily explained by the SD cards being "interchanged".

Comment: Thanks. Where Is the internal sd card? How to remove it?

Comment: Fixed into your device, and not without destroying it ([SoC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_on_a_chip)).

Comment: Internal storage: `/data`. SD cards are using `vold` (see output of `mount`). Useful reading: [Android Folder Hierarchy](http://android.stackexchange.com/posts/46934/edit), our [storage tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/storage/info).

Comment: Sorry, copy in my phone is bad. The picture in my last commend should be http://i.stack.imgur.com/02mtp.png. What Is "phone"? Is it the same as the internal sd card? So my last comment should be "(1) Is the internal sd card "internal storage", or "phone" in http://i.stack.imgur.com/02mtp.png, or something else? The first has similar name, but unmatching space. The second has similar space. (2) Do the outputs of mount and df show "internal storage", and "phone" as partitions and file systems? "

Comment: Did you follow the links? If so: "device storage" (sometimes called "internal storage"). If not: Now is the time :) And again: This is no chat, and also [not a forum](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/92107/192154). We've got a chat room for things like this, you've got the required rep to join. I'll stop responding here now, as this kind of discussion violates our rules, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

`/storage/sdcard0` is usually an "emulated SD card", in other words, your internal storage. Newer phones always have that "internal storage" which can't be physically removed from the phone, and serves as its "SD card", in a way that it stores apps and user data.

Comment: While I agree, the second screenshot clearly shows separate entries for `sdcard0` and `internalSD` – which are neither duplicate (different sizes reported). What device has 2 internal/emulated cards?

Comment: thanks. (1) I found there is indeed a 2GB external SD card, probably too vague to see in the last picture. (2) The matching in size in picture 1 and 2 implies `/storage/sdcard0` is the mounting point of the external SD card or its symbolic link . (3) My question is when I unmount the external SD card, `/storage/sdcard0` isn't empty. See picture 3 and 4 for before and after I unmount the external sd card.

Answer (score 1):

When running console under TWRP, external microSD card is: /system/sdcard1  works fine, but I just couldn't get to it through ADB. I'm using MIUI 8.5.3.0.  Finally found it:

I suspect the name will vary, so do ls in /storage

it should show up something like

```
2ABC-1XYZ   <<< this is it
emulated
self
```

Comment: You probably have been mistaken - it should never be under `/system`. It's a user-accessible directory after all. That "2ABC-1XYZ" stuff is the volume serial number of that storage and will be completely different across different storage, or the same storage after formatting.

Comment: @AndyYan not exactly sure what you mean, I'm logged in in TWRP console right now, and I can create folders (for example) on microSD card via cd /system/sdcard1

Comment: SD card is user accessible; `/system` is not (unless you're rooted). Therefore, SD card shouldn't be mounted inside `/system`, else it would be inaccessible through that route for the majority of unrooted users. This got me curious though... Can you still see and manipulate `/system/sdcard1` after you boot into the OS? It might be a mount point unique to TWRP.

Comment: I'm rooted. I have full access to microSD via /system/sdcard1 but only through TWRP console. Once booted into OS that path is gone. So through OS I access it using that volume serial. I couldn't find any other (more normal) way.

Comment: I assumed so. Starting Android 6.x the volume serial is the only reliable entry left in the OS. `/system/sdcard1` is likely created by **your device's** TWRP to make things easier. I emphasized that part because I've never seen that entry point there on any device I've owned, despite I load them all with TWRP and custom ROMs. Probably the maintainer of your device's TWRP likes this way... Can you tell me what your device is, so I could take a look at it later (for curiosity only)?

Comment: Ah, I see, thanks for the info! I was going to search more thoroughly for a "normal way" to access microSD from OS, so this will have to do then. My device is Redmi 3S+ running MIUI. Features/Price of it is very nice, but unlocking bootloader was a bit not so straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

It was such a pain that the SD mount point is often different across android devices that I wrote this `awk` one-liner (works on my 3 android devices) :

```
adb shell mount | awk '/emulated|sdcard0/{next}/(Removable|storage)\//{if($2=="on")print$3;else print$2}'
```